# Display custom taxonomy on my custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Hello I am very new at customizing themes, my problem is that on my new post type "listing" `single-lisiting.php` file I need to change the taxonomy category to be display to 4 new taxonomies: status, location, type, bedroom. The code I have is:

```
<span class="itemCategory"><span class="icon-folder-close"></span> <?php echo __( 'Published in ', THEMENAME );?></span><?php the_category(", ");  ?>
```

Do not know how to change it, could someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a custom taxonomy, you can't use `the_category()` -- that's reserved for the default WordPress `category` taxonomy.  Instead use `the_terms()`:

```
<span class="itemCategory">
<span class="icon-folder-close"></span>
<?php echo __( 'Published in ', THEMENAME );?>
</span>
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'status', '', ", ", '' );
```

should output the `status` taxonomy for your post.

#### Reference

- [`the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms)
- [Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

Comment: The problem is that the category is all ready used by the normal post type and have different terms, all ready create the new taxonomies to be able to sort by results, just need to add the right code into the new single-listing.php file that all ready have format.

Comment: Yeah, I hit ENTER in the middle of typing my answer.  It should be more complete now.  You'll need to use `the_terms()` instead of `the_category()`.

Comment: Just one more question, to show, the other 3 terms, how do I do that. location, type and bedroom

Comment: Just change the 2nd argument to `the_terms()` to each of your taxonomy names:  `the_terms( $post->ID, 'location', '', ', ', '' );` and so forth.  You'll need one call to `the_terms()` for each taxonomy name.